# Prevent click event from firing subscribe in knockout model

Tags: events, knockout.js, subscribe

I have a list of categories that when clicked shows their related items.
I can also select the category from a dropdown. 
If I change the dropdown selection, the same action gets called.
But when I click on a category, the dropdown cannot be refreshed the way I did it and I can't figure out a clean way to do it.

Here's a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BigStef/AWfE8/56/) to demonstrate my problem

**Update:**
I've managed to get it working by basically adding another observable for the category Id and use it to update as reflected in the fiddle.

Comment: f_martinez had a better solution! Look below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `<li>` binding to:

```
<li data-bind="click: $parent.selectedCategory">
```

and comment:

```
self.showItems = function(category){

    // ...

    // self.selectedCategory(category);

    // ...
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/AWfE8/60/

Comment: Well, that was the answer I was looking for! Thanks!